Why doesn't the "norebalance" flag prevent a healthy Ceph cluster from moving data to a newly added osd?
With a clean install of Ceph version 18.2.4, I tried to add a new OSD in a HEALTH_OK cluster without triggering data movement.
Setting the "norebalance" flag didn't prevent ceph to immediately move data to the new OSD.
Here is the trace of the commands I used :
# initial state: 3 hosts, 4 OSDs

$ ceph orch host ls
HOST       ADDR            LABELS  STATUS  
ceph01  192.168.101.10  _admin          
ceph02  192.168.101.11  _admin          
ceph03  192.168.101.12  _admin          
3 hosts in cluster

$ ceph osd tree
ID  CLASS  WEIGHT   TYPE NAME           STATUS  REWEIGHT  PRI-AFF
-1         0.02197  root default                                 
-3         0.01099      host ceph01                           
 0    hdd  0.00549          osd.0           up   1.00000  1.00000
 1    hdd  0.00549          osd.1           up   1.00000  1.00000
-5         0.01099      host ceph02                           
 2    hdd  0.00549          osd.2           up   1.00000  1.00000
 3    hdd  0.00549          osd.3           up   1.00000  1.00000

$ ceph -s
  cluster:
    id:     1ae2e354-6b87-11ef-aa6e-738d3ffe6d7d
    health: HEALTH_OK
 
  services:
    mon: 3 daemons, quorum ceph01,ceph03,ceph02 (age 6m)
    mgr: ceph01.mbuuym(active, since 7m), standbys: ceph03.acyoah
    osd: 4 osds: 4 up (since 6m), 4 in (since 6m)
 
  data:
    pools:   2 pools, 33 pgs
    objects: 111 objects, 404 MiB
    usage:   1007 MiB used, 21 GiB / 22 GiB avail
    pgs:     33 active+clean

$ ceph osd df
ID  CLASS  WEIGHT   REWEIGHT  SIZE     RAW USE   DATA     OMAP     META     AVAIL    %USE  VAR   PGS  STATUS
 0    hdd  0.00549   1.00000  5.6 GiB   219 MiB  158 MiB    1 KiB   61 MiB  5.4 GiB  3.83  0.87   12      up
 1    hdd  0.00549   1.00000  5.6 GiB   293 MiB  245 MiB    1 KiB   48 MiB  5.3 GiB  5.12  1.16   21      up
 2    hdd  0.00549   1.00000  5.6 GiB   173 MiB  130 MiB    1 KiB   44 MiB  5.4 GiB  3.03  0.69   11      up
 3    hdd  0.00549   1.00000  5.6 GiB   321 MiB  273 MiB    1 KiB   48 MiB  5.3 GiB  5.62  1.28   22      up
                       TOTAL   22 GiB  1007 MiB  806 MiB  6.2 KiB  201 MiB   21 GiB  4.40                   
MIN/MAX VAR: 0.69/1.28  STDDEV: 1.03

# adding a new OSD

$ ceph osd set norebalance
$ ceph orch daemon add osd ceph03:/dev/sdb 
Created osd(s) 4 on host 'ceph03'

# final state: 3 hosts, 5 OSDs

$ ceph osd tree
ID  CLASS  WEIGHT   TYPE NAME           STATUS  REWEIGHT  PRI-AFF
-1         0.02747  root default                                 
-3         0.01099      host ceph01                           
 0    hdd  0.00549          osd.0           up   1.00000  1.00000
 1    hdd  0.00549          osd.1           up   1.00000  1.00000
-5         0.01099      host ceph02                           
 2    hdd  0.00549          osd.2           up   1.00000  1.00000
 3    hdd  0.00549          osd.3           up   1.00000  1.00000
-7         0.00549      host ceph03                           
 4    hdd  0.00549          osd.4           up   1.00000  1.00000

$ ceph -s
  cluster:
    id:     1ae2e354-6b87-11ef-aa6e-738d3ffe6d7d
    health: HEALTH_WARN
            norebalance flag(s) set
            Reduced data availability: 3 pgs inactive, 1 pg peering
 
  services:
    mon: 3 daemons, quorum ceph01,ceph03,ceph02 (age 11m)
    mgr: ceph01.mbuuym(active, since 12m), standbys: ceph03.acyoah
    osd: 5 osds: 5 up (since 7s), 5 in (since 19s)
         flags norebalance
 
  data:
    pools:   2 pools, 33 pgs
    objects: 104 objects, 378 MiB
    usage:   988 MiB used, 27 GiB / 28 GiB avail
    pgs:     9.091% pgs unknown
             15.152% pgs not active
             23 active+clean
             4  peering
             3  unknown
             2  active+undersized+remapped
             1  remapped+peering

$ sleep 5m
$ ceph osd df
ID  CLASS  WEIGHT   REWEIGHT  SIZE     RAW USE  DATA     OMAP     META     AVAIL    %USE  VAR   PGS  STATUS
 0    hdd  0.00549   1.00000  5.6 GiB  182 MiB  121 MiB    1 KiB   61 MiB  5.4 GiB  3.19  0.87    9      up
 1    hdd  0.00549   1.00000  5.6 GiB  221 MiB  173 MiB    1 KiB   48 MiB  5.4 GiB  3.86  1.05   14      up
 2    hdd  0.00549   1.00000  5.6 GiB  163 MiB  102 MiB    1 KiB   61 MiB  5.4 GiB  2.85  0.78    8      up
 3    hdd  0.00549   1.00000  5.6 GiB  246 MiB  198 MiB    1 KiB   48 MiB  5.3 GiB  4.30  1.17   18      up
 4    hdd  0.00549   1.00000  5.6 GiB  240 MiB  214 MiB    1 KiB   26 MiB  5.4 GiB  4.20  1.14   17      up
                       TOTAL   28 GiB  1.0 GiB  808 MiB  7.8 KiB  245 MiB   27 GiB  3.68                   
MIN/MAX VAR: 0.78/1.17  STDDEV: 0.57
# new OSD #4 is already filled despite the "norebalance" flag

I'm particularly interested in understanding what happens in Ceph when a new
OSD is added to a healthy cluster, and why the "norebalance" flag doesn't prevent
data movement in this situation.
Here are a few questions I'd like answered:

what "events" (rebalancing, backfilling, recovering...) are triggered when
adding a new OSD to a healthy cluster ?
why are some PGs in "undersized+remapped" state just after adding the new
OSD, whereas they were not "undersized" before ?
what does "rebalancing" really mean in Ceph ? In which situation does it
occur ?
why doesn't the "norebalance" flag prevent data movement when adding a new OSD to a healthy cluster ?
in which situation is the "norebalance" flag usefull ?


You might want to move this question to a different forum like unix.stackexchange.com or serverfault.com. The norebalance flag isn't enough, you'll need the nobackfill flag as well, maybe also the norecovery flag. There are a couple of ways how to handle this, for example using osd_crush_initial_weight = 0, that doesn't trigger any data movement after adding OSDs (we use that). The disadvantage is that you'll have to reweight those OSDs manually, but it works well for us. There are a couple of threads out there tackling this.

Thanks for the suggestion to use osd_crush_initial_weight. However I'm more interested in the why than in the how. I've changed my question accordingly.

I might not remember it correctly, but I believe some of the osd flags like norebalance is applied to existing OSDs. But if you add new ones, they are not covered and therefore fully participate in the cluster.
